# Saving dataframe as a single file to AWS S3 through Apache-Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

How do I save a dataframe as a single file to AWS S3? I tried both repartition and coalesce , but didn't work. The data frame is saved as multiple part files in a folder, I need that to be saved as single file (myfile.csv)

```
val s3path="s3a://***:***@***/myfile.csv"
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(s3path)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: There is no error message, but the data frame is saved as multiple part files

Comment: can you show the output directory ?